# Why is flat object not working in rigid body?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Hello my dear blender artists,

why flat object don't work in rigid body?
i simulated two type objects : box and scaled box (Z axis scale that makes it flat).
but only box that hit the floor. the flat objects just went through it.
what is actually happening?
[image]

file : https://pasteall.org/blend/b42ef26e578c43b5a6709a50a3d3f600

something is wrong again. one file is collided while the other still went through.
[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without any details on the objects itself, did you apply the scale, is the origin in the center of mass, are all rigid body settings correct etc. Even better would be the file itself because there are a lot of possible reasons from what information you have given.

Comment: i agree with Gordon. You didn't give us enough information to solve your problem. So providing your blend file would be the best.

Comment: i already added the blend file. guys, please help.

Answer (score 1):

The objects are too thin, so you need to add **Collusion margin**:

[image]

Alternatively, try to use a more simple physics model than **convex hull**. Set **box** or **sphere** where you can.

Comment: i already tried the collusion margin and it worked! but, when i zoom closely, the flat part looks like its still levitating. but still another flat part still went through the floor